# d3 js markers don't display on map

Tags: d3.js

I have a problem with d3.js. Markers display below the map instead on it.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/raw/f3105fda25ff785dc5ed/tile.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/raw/f3105fda25ff785dc5ed/d3.quadtiles.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/raw/f3105fda25ff785dc5ed/d3.geo.raster.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emeeks/d3-carto-map/master/d3.carto.map.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<style>
.markerButton {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
  }

body {
  background: #fcfcfa;
}

.stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.fill {
  fill: #fff;
}

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

</style>
<body onload="makeSomeMaps()">




<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.mollweide()
    .scale(165)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
function circleMarker() {
    var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100,2000]).range([2,10,20]).clamp(true);
    var randomDatapoint = "r" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7);
    d3.selectAll("g.marker").selectAll("*").remove();
    d3.selectAll("g.marker").append("circle")
    .attr("class", "metro")
    .attr("r", function(d) {return sizeScale(d[randomDatapoint])})
  }
function makeSomeMaps() {
    map = d3.carto.map();




    d3.select("#map").call(map);
    map.centerOn([-99,39],"latlong");
    map.setScale(4);

    map.refresh();

cityLayer = d3.carto.layer.csv();
    cityLayer
    .path("cities.csv")
    .label("Metro Areas")
    .cssClass("metro")
    .renderMode("svg")
    .x("x")
    .y("y")
    .clickableFeatures(true)
    .on("load", function(){console.log(cityLayer.dataset())});

    map.addCartoLayer(cityLayer);

}



</script>
<div id="map">
<button style="left: 340px;" class="markerButton" onclick="circleMarker();">Circle Marker</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please find link to site live:
http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/mymap/d3_projection03.html

Perhaps it's something to do with `map.centerOn`?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the asynchronous rendering nature of html/javascript. I had a similar issue in the past and I solved it by defining different layers/groups for the map and the markers. Something like:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var map = svg.append("g");
var markers = svg.append("g");
```

and then append the map and the markers in these predefined layers. The markers will appear on top of the map because you define their layer after the map layer. In your case you should probably define a layer for each element (graticule layer etc.)

Comment: Can I ask Theod  how to define those layers? How the code should look like?I'm a newbie to javascript.

Comment: Define them just after the svg. Check the edited post. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your code.

Comment: I added the code Theod but the markers still display below the map:http://www.ewelinawoloszyn.com/mymap/d3_projection03.html

Comment: Could you tell me where the "g.marker" element is in your script. It seems to me that you are appending a marker to a non-existing element/container. Maybe try to replace d3.selectAll("g.marker").append("circle") with markers.append("circle")

Comment: I've replaced it as you suggested but still markers display under the map.

Comment: Perhaps you have any other suggestions @sTheod?